# How do I stop visual studio 2015 for web iis service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2015

When launching my MVC app built using [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view) tutorial, it uses IIS Express as server. When I want to go back to edit my application the IIS Express server doesn't stop the page, so next time I launch my MVC app it has not changed.

I can not stop the service using the IIS Express manager or windows service manager because Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web is the service owner.

Under my project properties, I can find settings for Servers under the Web tab, but nothing useful. Where / how can I make Visual Studio stop the service when I stop debugging my project?

Comment: Can you see an IIS server icon in you status bar (right hand side of the menu bar)?

Comment: Yes, but using it to Stop site doesn't do nothing. Neither does Show All Applications -> Stop All.

Comment: Have you tried making a separate host for your application? Without using Visual Studio 2015 emulated IIS instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by opening my project properties Web tab and clicking on the button **Create Virtual Directory**. Now I can stop the IIS Express service using IIS Express manager from the status bar.